# Pinia state lose dynamism when access to state property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, pinia

I'm using Pinia in Vue3. I use UserStore in the beforeEach method in Vue Router.
Above code works without any errors. This means there is no problem with the store connection.

index.store.js

```
const userStore = useUserStore()
userStore.login("admin", "1234")
```

When I try to get the user state with the code below, I do not receive any errors and it dynamically fetches updated data.

```
const userStore = useUserStore()
console.log(userStore.user)
```

When I say that, the data appears as undefined. As far as I understand, when fetching a property, it does not fetch its current state, but the first state in which it was defined in the store. It gives this error because the "username" property does not exist in the store.

```
const userStore = useUserStore()
console.log(userStore.user.username)
```

But there is a strange situation:

```
const userStore = useUserStore()
console.log((await userStore.login("admin", "1234").username)
```

I don't get an error and it fetches the value successfully.

user.store.js

```
    const user = reactive({
    })
    const inited = ref(false)
    
  const getUser = async () => {
    return user
  }

  const login = async(username, password)  => {
    const resp = await backendAPI.post("auth/login", {username, password})
    console.log('%cuser.js line:10 user.data', 'color: #007acc;', resp.data);
    if(resp.data) {
      localStorage.setItem("access_token", resp.data.access_token)
      Object.assign(user, resp.data.user)
      return user
    }
  }
```

Why does Pinia do something like this and how do I solve it?

Thanks for your help

I tried using toRaw method but it didnt work as well

Comment: It's unclear how you expect it to work and why. You can't access user before `await .login(...)`. " It gives this error" - which error? userStore.user.username === undefined in your case. "Above code works" - which code?